# How could I fix the lines being read?

Tags: bash

I have multiple commented out lines in a list of names.
I'm trying to read and number the exact line that they are only commented out.
My current lines from my output look like this.

```
Line 2: jimmy commented out & 
Line 3: tommy commented out.  tommy is line 4 not line 3.
```

I'm pretty sure I'm close or hope so. I'm just stuck and hoping someone could help a beginner.

blah file:

```
jim
#jimmy
tom
#tommy
```

Script file:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=1
input='blah'
while IFS= read -r Line; do
    Domain=$(echo "$Line" | grep -v "^[[:space:]*\#]")
    if [ -z "$Domain" ]; then
        echo "Line $n: $Line commented out"
        continue;
    fi
    n=$((n+1))
done < $input
```

This is what I'm trying to get.

```
Line 2: jimmy commented out & 
Line 4: tommy commented out
```

Comment: Could you indent your code properly? Make it easier to read and understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that the `continue` statement skip the line numbering and go straight to the end of the loop.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

n=1
input='blah'
while IFS= read -r Line; do
  Domain="${Line%%#*}"
  if [ -z "$Domain" ]; then
    echo "Line $n: $Line commented out"
  else
    : # do stuff with Domain
  fi
  n=$((n + 1))
done <$input
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply start `n` at 0 and move your counter above the conditional `continue`.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
input='blah'
while IFS= read -r Line; do
    n=$((n+1))
    Domain=$(echo "$Line" | grep -v "^[[:space:]*\#]")
    if [ -z "$Domain" ]; then
        echo "Line $n: $Line commented out"
        continue;
    fi
done < $input
```

Output:

```
Line 2: #jimmy commented out
Line 4: #tommy commented out
```

That said, you could do something similar much more succinctly:

```
$ grep -n '^#' blah
2:#jimmy
4:#tommy
```